# Add to publisher next methods changeVideoTrack/changeAudioTrack

Tags: opentok

Sometimes needs to change camera and cycleVideo is not good for this purposes because we cant control deviceId and its video/audio track

We need methods like (especially when it is different devices)

```
publisher.changeVideoTrack(myVideoTrack);
publisher.changeAudioTrack(myAudioTrack);
```

You can implement it (based on cycleVideo) very fast in opentok SDK.

At this moment to change stream track we are need to destroy publisher and create new one - its bad solution

Answer (score 0):

Adam here from the OpenTok team. Thank you for your feedback. You can currently change the audio track using the `setAudioSource()` method of the publisher. We also have a `setVideoSource()` on our roadmap to add in the future.

Comment: I agree with the OP, it's very hard to implement a pleasant UI when the audio and video methods are implemented completely differently.